# Flutter update instance in sqflite from form

Tags: flutter, sqflite

In my app I have an UserProfile which conatins a privatekey. When the app is first launched it checks whether the pk exists or not and if not displays a form to enter the pk. All this works fine. Now I have some problems on storing the entered value into my UserProfile. Here my form:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:voota/widgets/AppBar.dart';
import 'package:voota/widgets/Button.dart';
import 'package:voota/utils/Hex2Color.dart';
import 'package:voota/utils/UserProfile_dbHelper.dart';

class SetPrivateKey extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PrivateKey createState() => _PrivateKey();
}

class _PrivateKey extends State<SetPrivateKey> {
  final String title = 'Set Private Key';
  final bgcolor = HexToColor('#ffffff');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: BaseAppBar(title: title, appBar: AppBar()),
      backgroundColor: bgcolor,
      body: Center(
        child: PrivateKeyForm(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PrivateKeyForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PrivateKeyForm createState() => _PrivateKeyForm();
}

class _PrivateKeyForm extends State<PrivateKeyForm> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final TextEditingController _controller = new TextEditingController();

  var _userprofile = UserProfileDatabaseHelper().getUserProfile();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final int maxLength = 5;

    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: new Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
          color: Colors.white,
          child: new Container(
            child: new Center(
                child: new Column(children: [
              new Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0)),
              new Text(
                'Enter or Scan your Private Key',
                style:
                    new TextStyle(color: HexToColor("#F2A03D"), fontSize: 14.0),
              ),
              new Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0)),
              new TextFormField(
                maxLength: maxLength,
                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Private Key",
                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                  border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                    borderSide:
                        new BorderSide(color: Colors.orange, width: 2.0),
                  ),
                ),
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value.isEmpty || value.length < maxLength) {
                    return "Enter a valid private key";
                  } else {
                    return null;
                  }
                },
                onSaved: (value) async {
                  print('onSaved');
                },
                style: new TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: "Poppins",
                ),
              ),
              new Container(
                child: new Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new VootaButton(
                        text: 'Scan',
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                        buttonColor: Colors.green,
                        onPressed: () {}),
                    new RaisedButton.icon(
                        label: new Text("Save",
                            style: new TextStyle(
                                color: HexToColor("#FFFFFF"), fontSize: 14.0)),
                        icon:
                            new Icon(Icons.save, color: HexToColor("#FFFFFF")),
                        color: HexToColor('#508bbb'),
                        elevation: 5.0,
                        onPressed: _submitForm),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ])),
          )),
    );
  }

  void _submitForm() {
    final FormState formState = _formKey.currentState;

    if (!formState.validate()) {
      Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        content: Text('Form is not valid, please check !!'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
      ));
    } else {
      // hide keyboard
      FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
      // display a Snackbar.
      Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        content: Text('Processing and validating Private Key...'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
      ));

      formState.save();
    }
  }
}
```

The onSaved: is well executed and it is exactly here where I need your help. I just want to update the pk if the UserProfile already exist and if not, create a new one. Any help, suggestion or link are welcome. Thx.

Comment: Well, you need to implement a save and/or update function in your UserProfileDatabaseHelper and call it after formState.save. What exactly is your problem, currently the question is too broad.

Comment: That is exactly what I have done now and it works, thx.